# Какой модуль ядра linux управляет ip протоколом?

Tags: linux, сеть, tcp-ip

Интересно как отправляются данные по сети внутри linux, то есть где формируется пакет, к которому прикрепляются заголовки, ip адрес и кто дальше это отправляет на сетевую карту чтобы по проводам побежали данные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Книга 2003-го года: [Linux Networking Architecture](http://www.staroceans.org/kernel-and-driver/Prentice%20Hall%20-%20The%20Linux%20Networking%20Architecture%20Design%20and%20Implementation%20of%20Network%20Protocols%20in%20the%20Linux%20Kernel.pdf)

Презентация 2013-го года: [The TCP/IP Stack in the Linux Kernel](https://www.slideshare.net/divyekapoor/linux-tcp-ip-presentation)

Исходные тексты 2021 года: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/net

Собственно реализация стека TCP/IP:

- Для IPv4 https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/net/ipv4
- Для IPv6: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/net/ipv6

Помимо TCP/IP ядро линукса поддерживает много других протоколов. Их реализации лежат в каталогах внутри `/net`.

Краткое описание того, как формируется пакет, вы найдёте в презентации. Код, который строит пакеты и отправляет их в сетевой интерфейс, найдёте по ссылкам.